# my code runs for 15mins but only white output?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, stop-words

I'm doing a stop word code for data cleaning. I followed a tutorial in YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckQUlI7x7hI his code works and shows output but mine doesn't

I'm using english stop words, example of my stop words are "a", "an", "away", "keeps". the input will be "An apple a day keeps the doctor away" output should be "apple day the doctor".

this is the content of my file: https://ufile.io/gikev

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataCleaning {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList sw = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        FileInputStream x = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/stopwords.txt");

        byte b[] = new byte[x.available()];
        x.read(b);
            x.close();

            String data[] = new String(b).split("\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            sw.add(data[i].trim());
        }
         FileInputStream xx = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/cleandata.txt");

        byte bb[] = new byte[xx.available()];
        xx.read(bb);
            xx.close();

            String dataa[] = new String(bb).split("\n");



            for(int i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++)

        {
            String file = "";
            String s[] = dataa[i].split("\\s");
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length; i++)
            {
                if(sw.contains(s[j].trim().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    file=file + s[j] + " ";
                }

            }
            System.out.println(file + "\n");
        }

    } catch(Exception a){
        a.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

 }
```

and when I run mine it only does this:

[image]

what should I do?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? It would be much easier rather than going through the video

Comment: Im trying to clean my data by removing stop words from a txt file and the output must be the clean data.

Comment: An example also perhaps with a sample input and expected output? Do include them in your question.

Comment: I'm using english stop words, example of my stop words are "a", "an", "away", "keeps". the input will be "An apple a day keeps the doctor away" output should be "apple day the doctor".

Comment: 1. Are you trying to write the output to a file? 2. Where in your code are you filtering these *stop words*?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++)

        {
            String file = "";
            String s[] = dataa[i].split("\\s");
            for(int j = 0; j < s.length; i++)
            {
                if(sw.contains(s[j].trim().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    file=file + s[j] + " ";
                }

            }
            System.out.println(file + "\n");
        }

Comment: Argh. How does that code check if the file you are reading contains *"a", "an", "away", "keeps"*??

Comment: this code: FileInputStream x = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/stopwords.txt"); reads the file which contains stop words

Comment: Do share all this information in the question. What are the contents of this file?

Comment: I have uploaded the link

Comment: Use a debugger and go over your code step by step, checking what the variables contain.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and specially read the very helpful page linked at its bottom on debugging small programs. Many people find that creating an [mcve] helps them to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code :

1. You are incrementing the wrong variable in the innermost loop thus
   resulting in an infinite loop as `j` will always be lesser that
   `s.length` and you are never incrementing `j`. Change this line :

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < s.length; i++) {
   ```

   to

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
   ```
2. To print words that are *not stopwords* you need to negate your `if`
   condition as follows :

   ```
   if (!sw.contains(s[j].trim().toLowerCase()))
   ```
3. Also, make sure the file `stopwords.txt` is separated by `\n`(new
   line) because you are splitting it based on that and not like the
   file in the link shared by you.

*I recommend you to indent your code and also use meaningful names to name your variables. Debugging issues like this will be much simpler.*